# Array size in function declaration

Tags: c, arrays, prototype, declaration

I want to use a function that takes a two dimensional array of fixed size as parameter. The value of nm_pipe is known during the execution and the value of the other dimension is always 2.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    int num=2;
    int nm_pipes;
    /*some code that computes nm_pipe*/


    int pipe_container[nm_pipes][num];
    fill_pipe_container(nm_pipes,pipe_container);
}
```

Now, I have a problem with the declaration for the function `fill_pipe_containter`.

If I try somehting like this

`void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int pc[][]);`

I get an error because the array has no bounds.

If I try this:

`void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int **pc);`

I also get an error because of the type conversion.

I also tried this

`void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int (*pc)[2]);`

But I am pretty sure that it is wrong since that would mean that I expect a pointer on an array of 2 elements, however the program compiles with this one.

I can also do this:

`void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int pc[][2]);`

But I want to be able to declare the function without giving any size explicitly. What is the correct way of declaring this function and what should I avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int (*pc)[2]);
```

This one is the correct one. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, actually I got confused. It is one correct possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try `void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int pc[][num])`. Should be working.

Comment: Hmm no, that gives me `error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int**'`

Comment: And which error you get with `void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int **pc);`? `error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int**'`? :)

Comment: Try `void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int pc[][num])`. Should be working.

Comment: I get `error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int**' for argument '2' to 'void fill_pipe_container(int, int**)'` I suppose it is because I call it with the fix-sized array `fill_pipe_container(nm_pipes,pipe_container);`

Comment: Yes, it works. But as I say in my post, I want to know what is the best way of doing it. Without having the use `num` or `2` in the function declaration.

Comment: This is the best way according to http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html. This link also explains why you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int **pc);
```

and in the function call use this:

```
int **pipe=(int **)pipe_container;
fill_pipe_container(nm_pipes,pipe);
```

Comment: I've also tried this but doing so gives me a segfault when I try to modify an element in the function fill_pipe_container: `pc[0][0]=4;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the memory of the array in the heap:

```
int **pipe_container=(int **)malloc(nm_pipes*sizeof(int *));
int i;
for(i=0;i<nm_pipes;i++)
    pipe[i]=(int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int));
```

Prototype:

```
void fill_pipe_container(const int nmp,int **pc);
```

Then call the function:

```
fill_pipe_container(nm_pipes,pipe);
```

Comment: I don't want to use malloc here since I have a fixed size array

Comment: Yes, that is completely your choice. It does not matter whether you have a fixed size array or not you can allocate statically or dynamically whatever you want ! Also, The answer was only for your desire of declaring the function without the array size ! helped me anyway ! Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it is true that it allows to declare the function without the array size, thanks for mentioning it!